# Weird behavior of broken screen

Tags: hardware, touchscreen, broken-screen

My phone (OnePlus 6) fell just this morning right onto its screen, but at first I thought it's going to be fine, since I am a paranoid and got a bumper case and a screen protector for said phone. At first glance everything except the screen protector was perfectly fine, but upon trying to unlock the phone, all it showed was a black screen.

Regardless, I tried to use it, by connecting it with my PC and using adb, which worked perfectly fine. Since I wanted to narrow down the possible causes of the non-working (but seemingly fine, since there are absolutely no cracks) screen I tried some things, like unlocking with the fingerprint reader, or using the cameras, which all worked perfectly well. Just out of curiosity though I tried using the touch screen, which for whatever reason also actually worked.

Now on to my actual question: Has anyone had any expierence with a similar behaviour, or could think of any possible reason that the screen doesn't work, but the touch input does?

Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Your led lighting which is part of the digitizer s broken but the tough part survived. You would want to replace the led/digitizer. I've done this on a few phones and no longer attempt it to the fragile nature of the repair. eBay has services available for repairs